# Why there is a group member field in both /etc/group and /etc/gshadow

Tags: linux, users, group

I am learning more about Linux user and groups in depth and noticed fourth field in both [/etc/gshadow/](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Introduction_To_System_Administration/s3-acctsgrps-gshadow.html) and [/etc/group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/) are exactly same.

Do they have any difference or is there any special reason why it is duplicated in both file?

Answer (score 2):

The 4th field is a list of users that are members of the identified group. You can get a description of these two files with

```
man 5 group  
man 5 gshadow
```

I suspect the values in the two fields are the same for convenience. I don't offhand know what happens if the two lists are different.

Comment: This sounds like a _Bad Thing_ and _Random Problems Waiting To Happen_. If only there was a proper user database for Unix systems :-(

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Like windows registry haha